# I have no proof of employment to show my next company

Tags: job-search, new-job, india, relieving-letter

I was referred by an employee in a startup company as a developer. So without asking any salary details, I joined this company and started developing projects. Now it's been 7 months in this company and they still haven't paid me a single penny and they didn't give me an offer letter. I asked the person who referred me about these and he said he will talk to them but no proper response.

Now I am planning to quit the job in this company. If I get the job in the other company what should I answer if they ask why I quit? What if they asked for the documents like offer letter and relieving letter and pay slips?

Comment: `Now its been 7 months of my journey in this company still they didn't pay me a single penny` - How is it that you're able to live? Does someone else pay your bills? `If I get the job in the other company what should I answer if they ask Why are you quitting the previous company and they asked for the documents like offer letter and relieving letter and pay slips` - Why would they ask for that? Is it common where you are for companies to ask for this kind of information? In my country it's nobody's business but my own.

Comment: That sounds like slavery to me.

Comment: @joeqwerty believe it or not. In India a lot companies ask for such documents to verify all the statements provided during interview like duration of employment, salary etc. which is weird to me.

Comment: @joeqwerty here India most of the companies ask those documents. One of my senior failed to submit those documents in time he got rejected

Comment: @bhargavvenkatesh I edited your question to try and make it more clear and remove some of the extra questions (we try to do one question at a time here). Feel free to [edit] your question if  you want to add any other information.

Comment: How do you know the person who referred you? Are they a stranger who contacted you?

Comment: @DavidK the referred person is my neighbour and thank you for editing

Comment: And do you interact with other people at the company, or just your neighbor? It sounds like you're getting scammed here.

Comment: This is not an answer to your current specific problem, but last time I checked India was a democracy. So go out, inform yourself about the options you have and either vote for a party or support a movement to change your ridiculous labor laws and practices. They aren't set in stone. Go use your power and change them!

Comment: Do you have any other work experience besides these past 7 months?

Comment: Labor laws in India are designed to protect companies, not laborers.

Comment: As an aside... I don't know about Indian law, but in the US your "employer" wouldn't actually own any of the code you've been writing for them for the last 7 months. You might as well post all of it to your github/gitlab account so that you can make it part of your portfolio. If your "employer" wants to pay you for _your_ code, then you can take it down and you'll have real employment experience to talk about.

Comment: @bhargavvenkatesh You may also want to check out some of the top questions tagged [tag:relieving-letter], some of them ask what to do when you can't get one.

Comment: @DavidK i have interacted with him but no use he will just tell i will talk to them and sure I will search on that

Comment: @sf02 no this is my first job

Answer (score 10):

> I have no proof of employment to show my next company

Actually, you are currently not employed.  You have not been getting paid for your work and there is no documentation that proves that you have been doing any work for the past 7 months.

When applying to new companies, use the experience and documentation from your previous legitimate employers and answer questions regarding those previous employers accordingly.  Forget about your current "employer", act as if these 7 months never happened because you have no way of proving that they did.  If asked what you did the past 7 months you can say something like:

> While searching for new work opportunities I was working on improving my development skills.

It's not a lie because you have actually been doing developer work.  Hopefully you learn from this experience.

Comment: I answered some comapanies as I worked here and didn't get paid so they told we will take you as a fresher and we will train you for 3-6 months without paying and some will tell "we will get back to you"

Comment: @bhargavvenkatesh Unpaid internships/apprenticeships for people with no prior experience in the field are not uncommon in some countries. If you do decide to go for this option - make sure you set the expectations straight regarding what happens after those 3-6 months. Always get a signed contract, even for an unpaid internship.

Answer (score 6):

> Now I am planning to quit the job in this company.

Good better late than never.

> If I get the job in the other company what should I answer if they ask Why are you quitting the previous company and they asked for the documents like offer letter and relieving letter and pay slips.

You can tell them the truth. Most probably what they will be more concerned is about the work that you did there. So that they can see how you can be a suitable candidate for the role applied.

Other than that they can ask question like why did you work for free, how did you support yourselves for that period etc.

Most likely they will have their own systems in place to check whether the candidate is qualified to do something other than just believing past employment proofs like offer letter, pay slips, relieving letter, etc.

> What if I continue for one year in the existing company without salary and quit the job?

If I was in your place I would quit. I am not sure if you brought this topic to their attention or not but it's their business to see if employees are compensated or not. If they haven't discussed it yet there is a high chance they won't discuss this with you in future.

> What are the consequences I will face in the future?

Not much other than lost compensation for the period you worked.

> Since I started my job career recently so I am confused for the next step

Next step is to get things in place and get a job that pays unless you want to work for free.

Comment: I answered some comapanies as I worked here and didn't get paid so they told we will take you as a fresher and we will train you for 3-6 months without paying and some will tell "we will get back to you"

Comment: @bhargavvenkatesh just make sure you have correct paperwork next time to prove your work.

Comment: `Other than that they can ask question like why did you work for free, how did you support yourselves for that period etc.` This should be none of anyone's concern, and it's a red flag if a question like that pops up at an interview.

Comment: @Egor it will come to anyone's mind. It's not a red flag since they might want to know the reason why would someone work for free.

Comment: Why would they care? I don't see how knowing why a person worked for free will help them evaluate that person as a candidate for the job.

Comment: Every question in interview is not to evaluate for job. Who knows what answer OP gives and how it can be helpful for HR.

Comment: And OP has every right to not answer that question.

Comment: Exactly. These are the questions you shouldn't have to answer during an interview.

Answer (score 2):

> Now it's been 7 months in this company and they still haven't paid me
> a single penny and they didn't give me an offer letter.
>
> Now I am planning to quit the job in this company.

You can't quit a job you never had.

Answer (score 1):

No contract of employment may also mean that all the work you've done for them is not theirs, since there is no proof that you've ever worked for them and that you have confidentiality to keep - use this to your advantage. If it is an interesting project, upload to the internet and link it up on your CV to show what you've been doing for the last 7 months, since you definitely weren't employed.